# Can't connect to Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

I have a new computer that periodically fails to connect to Microsoft Teams. When this happens I am also unable to connect via Outlook. As a temporary fix, if I restart the computer I am able to connect to Teams and Outlook, but only for a few days.
I have reinstalled Office 365 and fully cleaned the system registry, but with the same results.

Comment: Most registry cleaners are snake oil at very best. Which one did you use?

Comment: Are you having network or Internet issues and it's just a timing coincidence? You say when it happens you can't connect to Outlook or Team but how about other websites, or https://outlook.com, or https://teams.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing the application through Windows firewall by typing "fire" on the search option of Windows 10 or 11. You'll then see one of the search results saying, "allow an app through Windows firewall", select it and then will take you to the simple firewall list. See illustration:

[image]

Comment: If this doesn't work then it might be a bug in Teams which Microsoft needs to address with an update OR if you're using an antivirus which might also be blocking it.